# ASP.Net Web api 2 case sensitive url query

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

I'm trying to pass data as a string parameter to a web api get method. I need to support both urls like `localhost/GetXml?s=Test and localhost/GetXml/Test`.

```
[RoutePrefix("GetXml")]
public class AnalyzerController : ApiController
{
    [Route]
    [Route("{s}")]
    [HttpGet]
    public string AnalyzeWord(string s)
    {
        return s;
    }
}
```

The problem is that the query string forcing lower case for some reason, but `/GetXml/Test` working as expected.

How can i make query string parameters be case sensitive?

Comment: Web API Query string dosent usually force lowercase query. and seems like there is nothing wrong with your code. are there any additional layers through which the query string passes before getting to the controller?

Comment: @ParvSharma ty for answer, yeah you right. This bug occurs only in Google Chrome. Edge/IE/Advanced REST Client produce correct data. But why google chrome forcing lower case for query parameters.

Comment: i couldnt even reproduce this on my dev machine with updated chrome

Comment: try using some other machine that you are currently using to reproduce the same error.